# Async TaskCompletionSource calling method twice

Tags: c#, async-await, c#-5.0

Having [found this way](http://softwareblog.alcedo.com/post/2012/01/25/TaskCompletionSource-in-real-life-%28part-2-of-2%29.aspx) of using `await` to call an async method with a callback, I've used it on the Argotic RSS reader library:

```
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

EventHandler<SyndicationResourceLoadedEventArgs> feedReaderOnLoaded = null;
feedReaderOnLoaded = (sender, args) =>
                {
                    feedReader.Loaded -= feedReaderOnLoaded;
                    tcs.SetResult(""); // Needed so the await completes
                };
feedReader.Loaded += feedReaderOnLoaded;
feedReader.LoadAsync(new Uri(feed.Url), new object());

await tcs.Task;

// Result is put in a property, rather than returned from the method
var items = feedReader.Channel.Items;
```

So that works nicely, and I get my items.

I noticed in Fiddler that two calls are being made to the url of the RSS feed. Upon stepping through the code in the debugger, it is called once on `LoadAsync`, and again on `await tcs.Task`. What should I do to eliminate one of the calls?

**UPDATE** There's a console app project that can be [downloaded from here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/9861259/AsyncPuzzle.zip) that demonstrates this behaviour.

**UPDATE** I've changed how I use the Argotic library, so that I download the RSS feed using an `HttpClient`, and then pass the contents to Argotic as a string, which now produces only one call. I'd still like to know why it was called twice, if anyone has any ideas.

Comment: Do you see the same effect if you *don't* use the debugger at all?

Comment: And if you don't use async at all? For example, is it possible that the reader simply makes two calls naturally (e.g. a HEAD then a GET)?

Comment: Yes, same effect, and they're both GETs. I'll revert to the sync version and comment again.

Comment: The sync version `feedReader.Load(XmlReader.Create(feed.Url))` makes only one call

Comment: Hmm. That *looks* okay to me. Can you put this into a short but complete console app I could try when I get home? Looks like something I'd enjoy digging deeper in, once I've reproduced it...

Comment: Of course, that's very kind of you.

Comment: I'm suspecting a problem in Argotic RSS. How many requests do you see if you use `LoadAsync`/`Loaded` without TCS?

Comment: Just saw the one request without TCS

Comment: I checked it without TCS and I get two requests, albeit the second one lags little behind. Not an issue with TCS, but with ArgoticRSS library itself.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is a bug/feature in the Async API for the [feed reader](http://argotic.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Argotic/Microsoft%20.NET%203.5/Argotic.Core/Syndication/Rss/RssFeed.cs).

It performs an async WebRequest to get the feed.
However, when it handles the WebRequest completion it create an XmlReader for the response, but actually uses:
`SyndicationEncodingUtility.CreateSafeNavigator(Url, new WebRequestOptions(), null)`
which reads it again (synchronously) from the source Url.

The feed itself will be cached the second time, so it doesn't cause a massive overhead.

Think it can be fixed by passing the response stream to `CreateSafeNavigator` but perhaps reading the response stream could benefit from being done async as well.